# Get first pattern matching in a line not using cut

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

having a bunch of texts similar to this (for the purpose of test and keeping data simpler as possible):

```
first 1 is the real 2 time the word matched 3 
appeared on the previous line but is 4 the fourth.
Every line can have more numbers 5 because numbers 6 are everywhere
I need to extract the number just after the word 7 that precedes 8
```

The `grep` command I'm testing to extract the first matching for the number just after the word is:

```
grep -Eoi ' [0-9]{1}'
```

the output is:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
```

Desired output is:

```
 1
 4
 5
 7
```

Not allowed to use `cut` nor `awk`.

Comment: Are any other utilities banned besides `awk` and `cut`, or does this have to be 100% totally in `grep`?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a kind of exercise mastering grep only.
Pure grep solution is this:

In a single line:

```
echo "first 1 is the real 2 time the word matched 3 " |grep -Eo '[0-9]' |grep -m1 -E '[0-9]'
```

Unfortunatelly using `grep -m1` in first grep is not giving the required result.

In a file with many lines, you have to use a loop:

```
while read -r line; do
grep -Eo '[0-9]' <<<"$line" |grep -m1 -E '[0-9]'
done < file.txt
```

Or in one command line:

```
while read -r line; do grep -Eo '[0-9]' <<<"$line" |grep -m1 -E '[0-9]';done < a.txt
```

Output is as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to use `sed`?

```
$ sed 's/[^[[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]\).*/\1/' << EOF
> first 1 is the real 2 time the word matched 3 
> appeared on the previous line but is 4 the fourth.
> Every line can have more numbers 5 because numbers 6 are everywhere
> I need to extract the number just after the word 7 that precedes 8
> EOF
1
4
5
7
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use *two* `grep` commands, first matching and returning everything up to the first sequence of decimal digits, then matching and returning only the digits:

```
grep -Eo '^[^0-9]*[0-9]{1,}' file | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,}'
```

[NOTE: I'm using `{1,}` since AFAIK `{1}` is redundant and I'm assuming you want to match decimal sequences.]

If you're allowed to use PCRE mode, and your `grep` supports it, you can do effectively the same thing in a single `grep`, by using the `\K` variable width lookbehind assertion:

```
grep -Po '^[^0-9]*\K[0-9]+' file
```

or (slightly more compactly, using the perl-style `\d` for a decimal digit):

```
grep -Po '^[^\d]*\K\d+' file
```

Or, since you *don't* say you *aren't* allowed to use `perl` itself you could split into space separated fields and then find the first all-digit field:

```
perl -MList::Util=first -alne 'print first { /^\d+$/ } @F'
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this sed and grep

```
$ sed "s/\([0-9]\)/\n\1\n/" input.txt | grep "^.$"
1
4
5
7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
grep -Eon ' [0-9]{1}' | sort -k1,1 -u
```

The output will be as follows (not sure if line numbers are the deal breakers):

```
1: 1
2: 4
3: 5
4: 7
```

Alternatively this expression will give you the output you want:

```
grep -Eon ' [0-9]{1}' | sort -k1,1 -u | grep -o ' .*'
```

Output (your output sample include leading blanks):

```
 1
 4
 5
 7
```